Auto generating polygons similar to initial study area in QGIS
In QGIS, I have a DEM and a polygon of my study area. My goal is to generate other polygons that have similar features as my study area (i.e. elevation range, slope, aspect, surface area).
I managed to get to the stage where I classified and vectorized the initial DEM to obtain pixels that have the same features as my study area and to mask the DEM based on that. With this new binary raster, I am trying to find a way to create polygons of fixed surface area (1090 km2) that encompass as many points as possible, so my new area is the most comparable to the initial one.
Do you know of a way to generate those? I do not use PyQGIS, but I will if this is the only way.

Could you share more details & screenshots of what you achieved and want to obtain,  ?
